# Numerical integral speed

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

I have the following code to calculate a numerical integral for any given a, however it takes a very long time, even with adaptivemontecarlo, which is not accurate enough:

```
 Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

 a=15

 g[t_] := {-(a + 2*Cos[2*t])*Sin[3*t], (a + 2*Cos[2*t])*Cos[3*t], 2*Sin[2*t]}

 dg[t_] := If[t - 2*Pi <= 0, g'[t], g'[2*Pi]];

 tfn :=
    NDSolveValue[
      {t'[s] == 1/Norm[dg[t[s]]], t[0] == 0, 
        WhenEvent[t[s] == 2*Pi, "StopIntegration"]}, 
      t, {s, 0, 2*Pi + NIntegrate[Norm[g'[t]], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]}];

 l := NIntegrate[Norm[D[g[t], t]], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]

 c1[s_] := g[tfn[s]]

 j[s_] := Normalize[Cross[D[c1[s], s], D[D[c1[s], s], s]]]
 v[s_] := Normalize[Cross[j[s], Normalize[D[c1[s], s]]]]

 T2[s_, y_] := c1[s] + 0.4*(j[s]*Sin[y] - v[s]*Cos [y])

 s := p
 y := 500*Pi*p/l

 der[x_?NumericQ] := (Norm[ND[T2[s, y], {p, 2}, x]])^2

 NIntegrate[der[x], {x, 0, l}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]/l
```

How could I improve the efficiency of this code?

#### Edit

I forgot to mention that the integral will be evaluated for many values of "a", and that's why I used a lot of := signs.

Disclaimer: I have opened a new thread since my question is different this time.

Comment: you can actually remove all of the delayed definitions except for `der`.  Change the `s` in the `NDSolveValue` expression to something else, so it doesnt get confused by your later unrleated assignment of s for some other purpose.

Comment: OK, I am trying your suggestions, but it takes incredibly long with = signs. The integration was taking 56 seconds with maxrecursion 10 and 23 with maxrecursion 1, where both gave the same result to a sufficient accuracy.     But I will calculate with 50 different values of a.

Comment: ND[T2[s, y] is the numerical derivative of T2. tfn is an interpolation function, so it is a function of s.

Comment: george2079, the s is the variable I used for arclength. It is same for all expressions.

Comment: Wrap `NDSolveValue` in `Module` : `Module[{s}, NDSolveValue[] ]` if you *really* must re-use the same symbol as the ode independent variable as you use elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of experience. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a stab at cleaning it up.  I put in table form so you can see how to loop over `a`.

```
 Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
 Table[
   g[t_] = {-(a + 2*Cos[2*t])*Sin[3*t], (a + 2*Cos[2*t])*Cos[3*t], 
       2*Sin[2*t]};
   dg[t_] = If[t - 2*Pi <= 0, g'[t], g'[2*Pi]];
   tfn = Module[{s}, NDSolveValue[{t'[s] == 1/Norm[dg[t[s]]], t[0] == 0,
       WhenEvent[t[s] == 2*Pi, "StopIntegration"]}, t,
          {s, 0, 2*Pi + NIntegrate[Norm[g'[t]], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]}]];
   el = NIntegrate[Norm[D[g[t], t]], {t, 0, 2*Pi}];
   c1[s_] = g[tfn[s]];
   j[s_] = Normalize[Cross[D[c1[s], s], D[D[c1[s], s], s]]];
   v[s_] = Normalize[Cross[j[s], Normalize[D[c1[s], s]]]];
   T2[s_, y_] = c1[s] + 0.4*(j[s]*Sin[y] - v[s]*Cos[y]);
   y = 500*Pi*s/el;
   der[x_?NumericQ] := (Norm[ND[T2[s, y], {s, 2}, x]])^2;
    {a, NIntegrate[der[x], {x, 0, el}, MaxRecursion -> 0]/el}  ,
      {a, 10, 10} ]
```

*NOTE* for testing purpose I put `MaxRecursion -> 0` so that `NIntegrate` finishes in some reasonable time (the result is highly inaccurate ).

This is your integrand:

[image]

You can increase `MaxRecursion`, but i doubt you will get any sort of accuracy.